# My media query command doesn't do the job

Tags: css, width, media-queries

I have kind of fluid and responsive layout - two divs:   .left and .right

how should I write my @media query command so that until the .container  doesn't hit more than 800 px width my .left and .right stays always 400 px width and when the width of container goes from 800 px and bigger my .left and .right go wider as well.

This command doesn't work :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) 


.container .row .columns.eight  {
  width: 400px;
}
```

And I also want my `.right` div not to fall down under the `.left` when I make the screen smaller.

Comment: marking an answer accepted closes the question, so please do so if, it served your purpose....or you have any doubt...just drop a comment!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media Query is not working because you have not enclosed the media-query in braces

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) 
 { /*<- missing from your code */
      .container .row .columns.eight  {
       width: 400px;
       }
 }/*<- missing from your code */
```

- To prevent div from wrapping to new line, add 
  `white-space:nowrap;` to the conatiner of those `.left /right` divs and 
   `display:inline-block;` to `.left` and `.right` div

[**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SvXs9/2/)  **~|~**
 [**fiddle with media query**](http://jsfiddle.net/SvXs9/4/)

**CSS**

```
.cont {
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
}
.right {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.left {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```